# Time difference (timeIntervalSinceDate)

Tags: objective-c, datetime, nsdate

I am having trouble with this bit of code, the output is always -596523 hours, -14 minutes.
any ideas?

```
NSDateFormatter *Formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[Formatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
NSDate date1 = nil;
if (count == 0) {
    date1 = [NSDate date];
    _startTime.text = [Formatter stringFromDate:date1];
    [sender setTitle:@"Stop" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}else {
    NSDate date2 = [NSDate date];
    _stopTime.text = [Formatter stringFromDate:date2];
    _startStopLabel.hidden = YES;

    long diff = (long)[date2 timeIntervalSinceDate:date1];
    diff /= 60; //Convert to minutes
    _totalTime.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d hours, %d minutes", diff/60, diff%60];
}
```

Comment: NSLog your two NSDate values.

Comment: The else branch will always measure the difference between date2 and nil.

Comment: @danh Move your comment to the answer section.

Comment: Thanks @danh, sorry for the late reply :)

Answer (score 0):

The else branch will always measure the difference between date2 and nil.